# Navigating to a different page within if statement

Tags: javascript, navigation, react-native

I'm building a React Native project using react-native-router-flux, and I'm having a bit of trouble with the navigation. Basically, I'm building a Login page that checks the email/password with the database, and stores the access token if matched. Then I want to instantly navigate from the Login page to the Homepage, but I'm not sure how to accomplish that. It seems like {Actions.SceneKey} only works when it's onPress. Here's my code for the Login Page:

```js
'use strict'

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AsyncStorage, StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight, AlertIOS,} from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux'
import t from 'tcomb-form-native'

import ViewContainer from '../components/ViewContainer';
import StatusBarBackground from '../components/StatusBarBackground';

var STORAGE_KEY = 'access_token';

var Form = t.form.Form;

var Person = t.struct({
  email: t.String,
  password: t.String
});

const options = {};

var LoginIndexScreen = React.createClass({

  async _onValueChange(item, selectedValue) {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(item, selectedValue);
      {Actions.HomeScreen}
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message);
    }
  },

  _userSignup() {
    var value = this.refs.form.getValue();
    if (value) { // if validation fails, value will be null
      fetch("https://EXAMPLE.herokuapp.com/oauth/token", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: value.email,
          password: value.password,
        })
      })
      .then(console.log(response))
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        this._onValueChange(STORAGE_KEY, responseData.id_token),
        AlertIOS.alert(
          "Signup Success!"
        )
      })
      .done();
    }
  },

_userLogin() {
    var value = this.refs.form.getValue();
        if (value) { // if validation fails, value will be null
          fetch("https://EXAMPLE.herokuapp.com/oauth/token", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              email: value.email,
              password: value.password,
            })
          })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseData) => {
            if (responseData.access_token) {
                console.log(responseData)
                this._onValueChange(STORAGE_KEY, responseData.access_token)
                {Actions.HomeScreen}
            } else {
                AlertIOS.alert(
                    "Login failed due to: " + responseData.message
                )
            }
          })
          .done();
        }
},

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Form
            ref="form"
            type={Person}
            options={options}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this._userSignup} underlayColor='#99d9f4'>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Signup</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
          <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this._userLogin} underlayColor='#99d9f4'>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 50,
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 30,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginBottom: 30
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: 'white',
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  button: {
    height: 36,
    backgroundColor: '#48BBEC',
    borderColor: '#48BBEC',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 8,
    marginBottom: 10,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
});

module.exports = LoginIndexScreen;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`Actions.SceneKey` is the medthod on `Actions`. So you need to call it like: `Actions.SceneKey()` or `Actions.HomeScreen()`.

When you put the method on `onPress` like this `onPress={Actions.HomeScreen}`, you are sending the method as a prop to `TouchableHighlight`, which gets called when you press on the button.

So, you need to call the method inside your if block as `Actions.HomeScreen()`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for me. I'm getting an error saying _reactNativeRouterFlux.Actions.HomeScreen is not a function.